# Get the pushed key_id for specific value in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new in firebase using on android.

The data is not getting saved to my firebase database. So I am not able to check whether this key, is the key I want....

```
String key_ID = mDatabaseRef.child("users").push().getKey();
mDatabaseRef.child(key_ID).setValue(My_Value_Object);
```

Comment: Are you certain you have permission to save data into the database? To detect this, see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/19721/detect-errors-when-writing-a-value-on-android#t=201702021420141047834

Comment: I'm not sure if you got the typo only here or on your code too. Key is different from key

Comment: Actually,
 mDatabaseRed.child("users").pust().setValue(My_Value_Object)
Works fine for me,, So @FrankvanPuffelen still there any chance for permissions or error issue...??

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes ,i just type here, i used same string value at both places...

Comment: Well.... the code is using `Key` (with an uppercase `K`) in the first line and `key` (with a lowercase `k`) in the second. Is that the problem?

Comment: No, @FrankvanPuffelen i just typed here, but i used same string name both places....

Comment: Are you sure `mDatabaseRef` has been initialized? Are you sure `My_Value_Object` isn't null?

Comment: Yes @RosárioPereiraFernandes , because when i insert value into firebase using mDatabaseRef.child("users").push().setValue(My_Value_Objects); values gets insert....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding one more variable for the reference of your push:

```
DatabaseReference pushRef = mDatabaseRef.child("users").push();
String key_ID = pushRef.getKey();
pushRef.setValue(My_Value_Object);
```

Comment: yes, it work. Thanks @RosárioPereiraFernandes .... But how i dont get it...

Comment: Apparently, when you were using `mDatabaseRef.child(key_ID)`, you were adding a child to your root reference (I am not sure this happened on your database, you should check it)